# ymaps баг карты в Firefox - тайлы карты с пробелами при отдалении

Tags: yandex-maps-api, firefox, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

подключен ymaps 0.2.1 через package.

при отдалении карты между тайлами появляются пробелы, тайлы выглядят как квадраты с border-radius

скриншот: https://ibb.co/VCMbpKn
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

наблюдается только в FF. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Очевидно, что какой-то CSS-фильтр скругляет тайлы карты наравне с прочими элементами страницы. Попробуйте найти и убрать лишний фильтр.

Comment: @YaCor'  благодарю, был border-radius для всех ymaps, а не только для контейнера, вопрос закрыт